# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. while importing project

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

I am getting this error while importing old project in android studio:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyDialer'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
}
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in error message. You should not define http protocol in maven repository url as it is insecure. Replace it with https:

```
    url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
```

should be

```
    url 'https://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
```